# Browserify doesn't link to my function

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am trying to use Browserify to refactor my project into modules. In my main file I have something like this:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var data = require('./cv-data.js');
var menu = require('./components/menuScript.js');
menu();
```

The jquery library and the data is imported correctly but when I try to use my menu function I get an error message Uncaught TypeError: menu is not a function. My menu script looks like this:

```
var menu = function() {
  console.log('hello'); // not really but lets say it looks like this.
}
module.export = menu;
```

I've tried many different ways of doing this but none seem to work.

```
var menu = {
  init: function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
}
module.export = menu;
```

and then:

```
var menu = require('./components/menuScript.js');
menu.init();
```

I'm sure I've missed something small, but can't see it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `exports`, **plural**:

```
module.exports = menu;
// ----------^
```